# How to create docking panel in Java?

Tags: java, swing

How do I create a docking panel in Java?

Comment: Can i ask what is a docking panel?

Answer (score 4):

If you mean to use a [Swing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swing_%28Java%29) docking framework in your application, there are some of them already existing:

- [InfoNode](http://www.infonode.net/index.html?idw)
- [MyDoggy](http://mydoggy.sourceforge.net/)
- <strike>[JDocking](https://jdocking.dev.java.net/)</strike><sup>1</sup>

However, if you mean adding a pure Java dock in the spirit of things like YzDock or other ones (The GNOME-DO extension is an other example), I think you'll have no other solution but to do it yourself. Fortunatly, there is some kind of [prior art](http://www.cs.umd.edu/hcil/fisheyemenu/fisheyemenu-demo.shtml) (yes, it uses text instead of images, but it's only a matter of `JMenuItem`/`JButton` contents).

<sub>1. This website is currently not available.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Also try [dock.javaforge.com](http://dock.javaforge.com/) - looks well, was recently updated and is licensed under the more permissive [LGPL 2.1](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/old-licenses/lgpl-2.1.html).